# How to get model attributes to save in order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a quiz app, to create a quiz I do this:

```
 def new
    @quiz = Quiz.new
    50.times do
    question = @quiz.questions.build
    5.times { question.answers.build }
  end
  end
enter code here
```

Which uses nested parameters. The problem is, sometimes the quiz doesn't save in order (such as when I create a new quiz OR I update an existing quiz). If I create a quiz in particular order, say Question 1, Question 2, Question 3, I want the questions in that quiz to remain in the same order after I update or create it. Right now, if I update a quiz the order gets jumbled up if I want to show the quiz using something like `quiz.questions.each do |question|`

I wasn't aware that ruby databases don't enforce order, so how do I make sure that if I create a quiz, the order in which I enter the questions (top to bottom) will always be the order that the questions are presented in?

If you are interested, this is the form I use to create the quiz:

```
<%= form_for(@quiz) do |f| %>
  <% if @quiz.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@quiz.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this quiz from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @quiz.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>


  </div>
<div class = 'field'>
     <%= f.label :difficulty, "Difficulty of Quiz, 1 to 3 with 3 being most difficult" %> 
    <%= f.text_field :difficulty %>

</div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :for_unsubscribed, "Check to have this quiz be visible to logged in but unsubscribed users" %>
    <%= f.check_box :for_unsubscribed %>


  </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question_attribute| %>
    <div class = 'inner-c'>
   <p>
    <%= question_attribute.label :content, "Question" %>    <span><b><%= question_attribute.index + 1 %></b></span> <br/> 
    <%= question_attribute.text_area :content, :cols => 100, :rows => 4 %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= question_attribute.label :explanation, "Answer Explanation" %> <br/>
    <%= question_attribute.text_area :explanation, :cols => 100, :rows => 6 %>

</p>
    <%= question_attribute.label :_destroy, "Remove Question"%> 
    <%= question_attribute.check_box :_destroy %><br/>

    <%= question_attribute.label :passage, "Reference Passage" %> <br/>
    <%= question_attribute.text_area :passage, :rows => 3, :class => 'passage-input' %>


    <%#= question_attribute.label :question_explanation, "Question Explanation" %>
    <%#= question_attribute.text_area :question_explanation, :rows => 10 %>


  </p>

   <%= question_attribute.fields_for :answers do |answer_attribute| %>
    <p>
      <%= answer_attribute.label :content, "Answer" %>
      <%= answer_attribute.text_field :content %>
      <%= answer_attribute.label :correct_answer, "Check to indicate correct answer", :class => 'inline' %>
      <%= answer_attribute.check_box :correct_answer, :class => 'inline'%>

    </p>
   <% end %> 

   </div> <!-- inner-c -->
 <% end %> 


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: have you tried setting a default scope on your model?  something like `scope :default, -> { order("created_at ASC") }` or maybe `scope :default, -> { order("id ASC") }` in order to enforce the order they are returned by your database? (the returned order is generally controlled by the DB, not rails). o as opposed to the default scope you can order your results in your controller. Else another option would be to perhaps add an index type filed. to control order. I've done this in the past as well.

Comment: It's not really a Ruby database issue. It's the database itself and possibly the driver. There's no requirement that you get results from a query in any particular order. You have to use the order by clause to enforce order. In your situation you have to decide what describes the order: the id, the created_at date or perhaps an arbitrary field you put in your model to represent order.

Comment: Thanks. Taking a look at my controller's new action, would the best way be to use id?

Comment: EDIT: I tried using both your suggestions but the error persists :(